# Ubuntu suddenly stopped booting and stuck on a specific screen

Tags: boot, 22.04

So this morning I started my pc and got this screen. I restarted several times and every time is the same. I run dual boot with Win10 (both OS's are on different drives though, also Win boots normally and is working).

I've never encountered this type of error and am stuck.

Ubuntu 22

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you post some more details about your system?
What you're seeing is your drive being mounted. Usually, after that step is completed, you should see the boot screen or the rest of the boot logs. In the picture you've sent it seems like it's stuck at ~2% of the way there. There could be a drive error at that point or, for all we know, the boot process could just freeze for whatever reason.

I suggest you try and carefully check the progress, and see if it changes. If it gets stuck at some number, the most likely case is that it encounters some sort of error in the drive that causes it to completely freeze. Just my guess tho.

Again, please share some relevant info on your system and drives, so that we can figure out what the issue is.